# Warning: makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: ios, casting, warnings

I am quite puzzled why this warning pops up. I use the same procedure on other controllers where it works perfectly.

> ConditionTableViewController.m:57: warning: passing argument 1 of 'initWithCondition:' makes integer from pointer without a cast

With the following code

```
- (void)managedObjectSelected:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject
{
// Load View
Condition *con = (Condition *)managedObject;
ConditionDetailViewController *detail = [[ConditionDetailViewController alloc] initWithCondition:con];

detail.title = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"cave"] valueForKey:@"title"];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                  style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:nil
                                 action:nil] autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
[detail release];
}
```

In ConditionDetailViewController.h

```
- (id)initWithCondition:(Condition *)aCondition;
```

Here the console output of "con"

```
2011-07-26 11:03:08.485 CaveConditions[10631:f203] <NSManagedObject: 0xe6628e0> (entity: Condition; id: 0xe6608b0 <x-coredata://368AFBD3-2C66-4ED7-977D-AB8EED8BB577/Condition/p149> ; data: {
    cave = "0x67486e0 <x-coredata://368AFBD3-2C66-4ED7-977D-AB8EED8BB577/Cave/p7>";
    ccId = 678;
    comment = "";
    diveDate = 1286830059;
    flow = "0xe668270 <x-coredata://368AFBD3-2C66-4ED7-977D-AB8EED8BB577/Flow/p1>";
    imageURL = "orbe_doof.jpg";
    insertDate = nil;
    ip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    line = "0xe668280 <x-coredata://368AFBD3-2C66-4ED7-977D-AB8EED8BB577/Line/p1>";
    percolation = "0xe668290 <x-coredata://368AFBD3-2C66-4ED7-977D-AB8EED8BB577/Percolation/p5>";
    sediment = "0xe6682a0 <x-coredata://368AFBD3-2C66-4ED7-977D-AB8EED8BB577/Sediment/p2>";
    temperature = 13;
    userMail = "xxx@xxx.ch";
    username = "Hans K...";
    visibility = "0xe6682b0 <x-coredata://368AFBD3-2C66-4ED7-977D-AB8EED8BB577/Visibility/p7>";
})
```

Includes as requested

ConditionTableViewController.h

```
#import "CellTableViewController.h"
#import "Cave.h"
```

ConditionTableViewController.m (Where the managedObjectSelected method gets called)

```
#import "ConditionTableViewController.h"
#import "ConditionDetailViewController.h"
```

ConditionDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Condition.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

ConditionDetailViewController.m

```
#import "ConditionDetailViewController.h"
#import "DataProcessor.h"
#import "PhotoViewController.h"
```

Comment: Does your code also `#import "ConditionDetailViewController.h"` ? Do you also get a warning like `blabla may not respond to message "initWithCondition:"` ?

Comment: It is imported. And it is the only warning I get. The funny bit is that it works even with that warning on the simulator. But not on the iphone

Comment: did you try perform a clean and build?

Comment: If you mean Product -> Clean then yes. It didn't work

Comment: Then to avoid warning you can do one thing and there is no harm in doing that. change the function like this - (id)initWithCondition:(id)aCondition; and then in the function you can check using like this if([aCondition isKindOfClass:[Condition class]])//proceed further otherwise show some error or do whatever you want.

Comment: Get the same error when I do that. And passing it like this -> ConditionDetailViewController *detail = [[ConditionDetailViewController alloc] initWithCondition:managedObject];

Comment: Could you please show us the #import section of all related files?

Comment: Edited my previous post with the imports.

Comment: Did you check for duplicates already i.e. if there are more classes with same name and if there is another ConditionDetailViewController.h in file system that was left after refactoring and contains an old revision?

Comment: Actually I did remove files and copy them again into the project. But I can't find any leftovers or anything.

Comment: Somehow it solved by it self after rebooting the mac :D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initWithCondition:` is a method of the `NSConditionLock` class in the Foundation framework that takes an integer. I think Xcode has somehow confused the symbol names `initWithCondition:` from two classes, and is using the wrong version. If your code is correct, including importing the correct headers in every file, it's probably a faulty index or precompiled header. Try deleting the derived data for the project from the "Projects" section of the "Organizer" window, and rebuilding the project.